# Check Local Windows Version History after Upgrade

Tags: windows, upgrade

Is there a way to check if Windows was upgraded from a previous version? I want to make use of the SetupComplete.cmd script, but only if the Installation was an upgrade (from Windows 7/8/8.1) and not if it was a fresh installation to a blank system.

My favorite would be a registry key that shows the previous verion or maybe the build number or something like that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade!DownlevelBuildNumber
```

This key / value seems to be my solution.